# Multiple Slugs conflict admin Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

i have 2 routes, one for the admin and other posts, but they are conflicting, since in the Posts routes i could have another slug that is the category.

Example:

```
Route::get('{category?}/{slug}',
    [\App\Http\Controllers\Site\PostController::class, 'show']);

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');...
```

How can i resolve it without adding other prefix to the Post or Admin? I see in the docs that i can use regular expressions but there isnt a ways of for example ignoring the "admin" word or something

Comment: If I remember correctly (or at least how it used to work), the routes will be checked in the order they are added so try and add the admin routes first.

Comment: @BenGooding - I think they know this since the specifically asked for a solution that did not require adding a prefix.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad I didn't read it fully

Answer (score 2):

Routes are compiled in order, so just change you routes order, they should be like:

```
Route::get('admin/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');

Route::get('{category?}/{slug}',[\App\Http\Controllers\Site\PostController::class, 'show']);
```